# DrawerLayout item change image

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I implemented a DrawerLayout in my application and I want if it's possible to change the image of an item when the status is status pressed. Hi have the following code which represent the template of an item in the drawer layout. I know how to change the color of an entire item when the status is pressed but I don't know how to change the image because the image is a child of the LinearLayout. Can anyone help me or suggest me a way to do it ?

Thanks

Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/CustomSelector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="65dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#5AC834"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#334370"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector to achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/CustomSelector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minHeight="65dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#5AC834"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_selector"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#334370"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Create icon_selector.xml under res/drawable folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />

</selector>
```

If you want to change the selector programatically you can change like below.

```
StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pressed));
states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.focused));
states.addState(new int[] { },
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.normal));
imageView.setImageDrawable(states);
```

Comment: Hi. It could be a solution if this would just a single item but this is a template for a DrawerLayout and every item has a different image which I set it programatically from my custom adapter....It would not work in this way. Thanks

Comment: @CalinCosmin, i have updated my answer to change the selector images programatically